# how to stream ip cam over html/htm in android

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, ip-camera

I am writing an android app that shows stream from my ip camera . The issue i'm facing is that when I enter url of camera in my browser and after authentication , it displays an html page that shows the stream , the url is

http://192.168.1.103:81/index.htm

I've done a lot of googling and tried several codes but they all fail as they assume the url as something like http://ip:port/video.mjpeg
In my case , I don't have the video but an html page streaming the video and hence unable to get the stream programmatically. Kindly help me for my final thesis project . Thanks in advance !! :(((

```
package com.example.ipcam;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.ipcam.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements           MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener , SurfaceHolder.Callback {
final static String USERNAME = "admin";
final static String PASSWORD = "";
final static String Rtsp_URL = "http://192.168.1.103:81/index.htm";

private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.black);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    _surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    _surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(320, 240);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sh, int f, int w, int h) {}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh){
    _mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_surfaceHolder);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Map<String, String>headers = getRtspHeaders();
    Uri source = Uri.parse(Rtsp_URL);

    try{
        _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);
         _mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
         _mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
          catch (Exception e) {
              }
          }


        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sh) {
          _mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        private Map<String, String> getRtspHeaders() {
              Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
              String basicAuthValue = getBasicAuthValue(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
              headers.put("Authorization", basicAuthValue);
              return headers;
            }

            private String getBasicAuthValue(String usr, String pwd) {
              String credentials = usr + ":" + pwd;
              int flags = Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP;
              byte[] bytes = credentials.getBytes();
              return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(bytes, flags);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
              _mediaPlayer.start();
            }
}
```

I've tried http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/01/25/video-streaming-from-an-ip-camera-to-an-android-phone
but nothing seems to work .

Comment: @SaschaKolberg what code are you expecting..

Comment: 1) You write "hence unable to get the stream programmatically", so I guess you have tried something programatically. 2) StackOverflow is about programming. So, as you are you trying to program an android app to show the video, I'd expect *android code* of at least an activity, possibly with a WebView and a layout xml.

Comment: im sorry, i just posted my android code . @SaschaKolberg

Comment: im trying to program an android app that can view live stream of my ip cam and i just posted my codes here . i hope you can help me :( @SaschaKolberg

Comment: Your *URI* obviously isn't a RTSP *URI*. You will have to read and parse the html page, searching for a valid streaming link, if one is available. What ip cam are you using, does it support something like *ZeroConf*?

Comment: im using SRICAM P2P Wireless IP Camera AP001 and i dont think it support ZeroConf.

Comment: im using SRICAM P2P Wireless IP Camera AP001 and i dont think it support ZeroConf.. im sorry i just dont have any idea. Im new to android :(( @SaschaKolberg

Comment: I think before you can start programming your app you need to do some more research concerning your ip cam and how to get a stream link for it. This is not an android problem. Try to open the html page in your browser and then view the source of the page. Search for a video URI and use that for your media player. If you can't find one, you'll have to explore other options (like trying to get the uri using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)).

Comment: okay i will do some more research, thank you for the info ;) @SaschaKolberg

Answer (score 0):

http://visitor:visitor@888.888.888.888:88/videostream.cgi

use this to auto login to the camera, visitor visitor is username and password